# Las etiquetas [jsonarray] y [jsonobject] no tienen orientación de uso ¿deberían usarse sólo para para preguntas sobre Java?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, desambiguación-etiquetas

[jsonarray](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonarray) y [jsonobject](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsonobject) no tienen orientación de uso ni wiki de etiqueta. He investigado un poco y he encontrado `JSONObject` y `JSONArray` en la documentación de Java y de Android.

En la documentación sobre JSON no lo he he encontrado los términos unidos, sólo por separado.

¿Estas etiquetas deberían usarse sólo para para preguntas sobre Java y Android?

Comment: Yo no estoy de acuerdo.. si vamos a crear etiquetas para cada objeto que tenga un lenguaje.. no vamos a terminar mas...

Comment: @gbianchi La pregunta no sugiere eso, es sobre etiquetas que ya existen. ¿Acaso estás proponiendo que sean quemadas?

Comment: y.. yo cuando veo cosas asi, las elimino...

Comment: @Rubén No, puede usarse para cualquier lenguaje que consuma un objeto JSON, no para un lenguaje en especifico

Comment: @Rubén Si esta bien solo que exista una etiqueta de JSON para que sea general

Answer (score 2):

Ahora mismo hay más de 20 preguntas con una u otra etiqueta, creo que deberíamos quemarlas porque no ofrecen nada que no tengamos con [java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) más [json](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json), por ejemplo (JsonArray y JsonObject son interfaces que forman parte de JEE y JSONArray y JSONObject son clases de las librerías estándar de Android).